# MYSQL and Normalisation: How to handle lots of optional fields?

Tags: mysql, normalization

I have a profile page with about 20 optional fields on it. To keep it normalised would I have to create 20 different tables and then do a query with 20 `JOINS` in it. That seems a bit over the top to me.

Is that the best way to do it?

Do you recommend that I keep it normalised?

Comment: an 'optional' field just means the value can be null... not sure why you think that means 20 additional tables.

Comment: @Andy note that there are multiple normalization forms.  You may find it helpful to determine up front which one you're aiming at, and also to decide how important performance, storage space, maintainability, adaptability etc. are.  Otherwise you're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: because having null 10 million times in one table means its not normalised

Comment: Having null even *once* in any table means it is not normalised. All the conventional Normal Forms assume that relations consist exclusively of regular values within their tuples - never nulls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to do this (although a bit confusing unless you know what's going on) is using the same design wordpress uses - as far as I remember it was called entity attribute value (Thanks to @Matt Fenwick). https://stackoverflow.com/tags/eav/info

Basic idea is that, instead of your 20 `INNER JOIN`-able tables to store odds and ends, you have two tables. One stores your entity (a post in wordpress' case) and the second stores all your odds and ends - or metadata as WP refers to it.
Instead of having a column for each data point, you have a column for name, one for value, and one for the ID of the entity that this property applies to.

This way you save yourself a ton of SQL, headaches during extension and time required to build it to begin with. If you ever need to cater for another property, you just bung it in there with the rest - no hacking the schema.

Some more detail on WP's database layout (here I'm thinking mostly of the wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables): http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

So an example might be (pseudocode, sorry):

```
table: yourEntity
entityID  int, primary key, auto increment
title     varchar

table: yourEntityMeta
entityID  int, non-unique key
name      text
value     text
```

This way you can have any number of properties for each entity with no restrictions or performance concerns over unused columns with `NULL` values and 18 more tables that need joining.

Hope this helps

Note: one issue with this (pointed out by @ypercube in the comments) is that using this means you can't specify the data type for each attribute, i.e a date attribute would be stored as text, as would a boolean or int. You also wouldn't be able to use a foriegn key to link to a table of valid values (thanks to @Catcall). You would need to consider this carefully before going down this route.

Comment: @jammypeach so basically I keep all values in one column that are separated by commas or something like that?

Comment: @jammypeach: The main reason to NOT do EAV is that you lose integrity enforcement. Everything is `text` as in your example.

Comment: @MattFenwick that's the cookie, thanks. @Andy Lobel no, you would use a new row for each attribute / value pair - i.e colour=blue, name=kitty, age=2 would be 3 separate rows. You could use a `group concat` on them to get a list if that's how you needed them.

Comment: @ypercube yep. The OP didn't specify any requirements in that regard but that's a valid point, see updated answer.

Comment: @jammypeach could always put a column for type and then typecast it in php haha, anyways all of the fields are strings so it doesn't matter

Comment: @jammypeach: The issue is not simply that you can't specify the data type for each attribute, and that's not quite what ypercube was getting at. The bigger issue is that you have no control over the domain for each property. For example, the dbms can't easily enforce the requirement that property_a be a number between 1 and 5, or that property_b be either "male" or "female".

Comment: @Catcall to be honest as far as I can see that's pretty much the same thing. If you can't make property_a an enum then neither can you specify which values you could insert - one depends on the other. On a different note, I don't see why you'd want to have that degree of constraints on data, considering how things change over time I've always found it much less work and hair pulling just to handle data validation and sanity checking in the app itself rather than in the db - tends to give me alot less fatal DB errors too.

Comment: @jammypeach: You said, "If you can't make property_a an enum then neither can you specify which values you could insert." Most database designers don't use enums; most use foreign keys to tables of valid values. You can't do that with EAV. Others have weighed in on the foolishness of [handling data validation only in application code](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2450/1064).

Comment: @Catcall ah I see - thought you were talking about enums. I've done that before too, when required. But after reading your link it seems this gap in viewpoints isn't unique to us or this question, rather web devs vs database devs. good read though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use nullable columns for the optional fields. The table will get quite large, but so many joins will just degrade your performance, and I cannot find a reason why this fields should be normalized, if they belong to one Object and will be updated together.

Answer (score 0):

If the option fields are constants, consider using an ENUM (for 2-20 options), however this method has its own pitfalls.

If your primary concern is database normalisation, you should have the separate 'look-up' tables for each option field, even if you have 20 option fields, so that you don't store duplicate data.

Also, if you decide to change the options in the future it makes your table a lot easier to maintain in the future.

The JOIN statements aren't that bad, and MySQL can support upto 61 tables in one query. I already explored that topic in [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154466/mysql-is-there-a-limit-to-innerjoin).

Comment: makes sense (i think enum is the same as what jammypeach said). I would upvote it to 1 but i already upvoted it from -1 lolll